# Dynamic override a Property

Tags: c#, dynamic

I am trying to build something similar to the EF Code first Framework, I am running in to a roadblock on how they are overriding the virtual properties in the object classes at runtime..

If i wanted to set a static get of a virtual property how would i go about some thing like that ???

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you can't override static properties. If you're talking about actual overriding at runtime, look at the castle dynamic proxy or linfu.